Missing styles in primevue + tailwind
I'm using Primevue with Tailwind with the following config:
"@primevue/themes": "^4.0.0",
"pinia": "^2.1.7",
"primeicons": "^7.0.0",
"primevue": "^4.0.0",
"tailwindcss-primeui": "^0.3.4",
"vue": "^3.4.29",
"vue-router": "^4.3.3

I find there are missing Tailwind styles. For example basis-1/4 works but basis-3/4 does not. and text-2xl works but text-4xl does not.
What am I missing here?

Could you please add your tailwind.config.js file for reference?
